# ReactJS and Flux handleButtonClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, flux

I want to implement a button that rerenders on click, just the button, but instead my whole view rerenders and I think its the way im thinking about components

I have a structure like this

```
<App>
 <AllEmployees>
   <EmployeeButton/>
 <AllEmployees>
</App>
```

Where on employee button click I assign a employee to a boss, so that employee is owned by etc. On button click I send a post request to my api and it successfully updates my api. So the back end is fine, but when it comes to the front-end flux logic I want to make it so that only the button is rerendered on click.

For example I have a api that gives me All employees and my stores listen for any change in that array AllEmployees [ ]. If that employee is owned then I want the button to be red, and say 'remove user', if it isn't then it is blue and should say 'assign user'. However I can't get it to work without rerendering my table in the front end(which is my AllEmployees array just populated into a table). I also want the front end to be able to tell if that user is already owned by a another Employee on page load as well.

My approach to it was when the action dispatched and the api completed, dispatch that data, and check if any employees are already owned, by checking if the users in the data belong to the current logged users "Owns : []" array, if so set a new condition called isOwned to True.

Then on the buttonClick, where it sends the post request, if the employee at that array Owned is set true, then set it to false and vice versa. I also added two variables there called "buttonText" and "buttonColors" to the object.

Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import UserActions from 'actions/UserActions';
import UserStore from 'stores/UserStore';
export default class EmployeesButton extends React.Component {
constructor(props: {
    id: String;
    buttonText: String;
    buttonClass: String;
}) {
    super(props);
    this.state = UserStore.getState();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    UserStore.listen(this._onChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    UserStore.unlisten(this._onChange);
  }

  _onChange = () => {
    this.setState({
      allUsers: UserStore.getState().allUsers,
      search: UserStore.getState().allUsers,
      user: UserStore.getState().user,
      userProfile: UserStore.getState().userProfile.profile,
      userProfileFull: UserStore.getState().userProfile,
      myEmployees: UserStore.getState().lackeys,
      myId: UserStore.getState().userProfile._id
    });
  }

render() {
    let id = this.props.id;
    let buttonClass = this.props.buttonClass;
    let buttonText = this.props.buttonText;
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick = {function(event) { let data = id; UserActions.handleEmployeeUpdate({data: data});}} className ={buttonClass}>{buttonText}</button>
    </div>
        );
}
}
```

AllEmployees.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import 'scss/main.scss';
import UserActions from 'actions/UserActions';
import UserStore from 'stores/UserStore';
import {Link} from 'react-router';
import EmployeesButton from './aEmployeesButton';
export default class AllEmployees extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = UserStore.getState();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    UserActions.fetchUserProfile();
    UserActions.fetchAllUsers();
    UserStore.listen(this._onChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    UserStore.unlisten(this._onChange);
  }

  _onChange = () => {
    this.setState({
      allUsers: UserStore.getState().allUsers,
      search: UserStore.getState().allUsers,
      user: UserStore.getState().user,
      userProfile: UserStore.getState().userProfile.profile,
      userProfileFull: UserStore.getState().userProfile,
      myEmployees: UserStore.getState().lackeys,
      myId: UserStore.getState().userProfile._id
    });
  }
  return (
      <div>
        <main>
        <h1>All Employees</h1>
        <div className = "AEmp">

        <table className ="table table-bordered table-hover data-toggle table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Email</th><th>First Name</th> <th>Last Name</th> <th>DoB</th> <th> Department</th> <th>Position</th> <th>Assign as your Employee</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
          <tbody>
          {allUsers.map((user) =>
            <tr key={'user' + user._id}>
              <td>{user.email}</td> <td>{user.profile.firstName}</td> <td>{user.profile.lastName}</td> <td>{user.profile.dob}</td> <td>{user.profile.department}</td> <td>{user.profile.department}</td> <td><EmployeesButton buttonClass = {user.buttonClass} buttonText = {user.buttonText} id ={user._id}/></td>
            </tr>
          )}</tbody>
          </table>
          </div>
        </main>
      </div>
    );
}
}
```

The Store:

```
import Immutable from 'immutable';
import UserActions from 'actions/UserActions';
import alt from 'altInstance';


class UserStore {
 constructor() {
    this.user = Immutable.Map({});
    this.userProfile = [];
    this.allUsers = [];
    this.lackeys = [];
    // (lifecycleMethod: string, handler: function): undefined
    // on: This method can be used to listen to Lifecycle events. Normally they would set up in the constructor
    this.on('init', this.bootstrap);
    this.on('bootstrap', this.bootstrap);

    // (listenersMap: object): undefined
    // bindListeners accepts an object where the keys correspond to the method in your
    // StoreModel and the values can either be an array of action symbols or a single action symbol.
    this.bindListeners({
      handleLoginAttempt: UserActions.MANUALLOGIN,
      handleLoginSuccess: UserActions.LOGINSUCCESS,
      handleLogoutAttempt: UserActions.LOGOUT,
      handleLogoutSuccess: UserActions.LOGOUTSUCCESS,
      handleFetchUserProfile: UserActions.FETCH_USER_PROFILE,
      handleFetchUserProfileComplete: UserActions.FETCH_USER_PROFILE_COMPLETE,
      handleFetchUserProfileError: UserActions.FETCH_USER_PROFILE_ERROR,
      handleUpdateSuccess: UserActions.UPDATE_PROFILE_SUCCESS,
      handleFetchAllUsers: UserActions.FETCH_ALL_USERS,
      handleFetchAllUsersComplete: UserActions.FETCH_ALL_USERS_COMPLETE,
      handleFetchAllUsersError: UserActions.FETCH_ALL_USERS_ERROR,
      handleEmployeeUpdateComplete: UserActions.HANDLE_EMPLOYEE_UPDATE_COMPLETE
    });
  }

  bootstrap() {
    if (!Immutable.Map.isMap(this.user)) {
      this.user = Immutable.fromJS(this.user);
    }
  }

  handleEmployeeUpdateComplete(data) {
    let uid = data.data;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.allUsers.length; i++) {
      if (uid == this.allUsers[i]._id) {
        if (this.allUsers[i].isOwned == false || this.allUsers[i].isOwned == null) {
          this.allUsers[i].isOwned = true;
          this.allUsers[i].buttonText = 'Remove me as a employee';
          this.allUsers[i].buttonClass = 'btn btn-danger';
        } else {
          this.allUsers[i].isOwned = false;
          this.allUsers[i].buttonText = 'Assign me as a employee';
          this.allUsers[i].buttonClass = 'btn btn-primary';
        }
      }
    }
    this.emitChange();
  }

  handleEmployeeUpdateError(error) {
    this.error = error;
  }
  handleFetchUserProfile() {
    this.userProfile = [];
    this.lackeys = [];
    this.emitChange();
  }

  handleFetchUserProfileComplete(profile) {
    this.userProfile = profile;
    this.lackeys = profile.lackeys;
    this.emitChange();
  }

  handleFetchUserProfileError(error) {
    this.error = error;
    this.emitChange();
  }

  handleFetchAllUsers() {
    this.allUsers = [];
    this.emitChange();
  }

  handleFetchAllUsersComplete(users) {
    for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
      users[i].isOwned = false;
      users[i].buttonText = 'Assign me as a employee';
      users[i].buttonClass = 'btn btn-primary';
    }
    this.allUsers = users;

  }

  handleFetchAllUsersError(error) {
    this.error = error;
  }

  handleLoginAttempt() {
    this.user = this.user.set('isWaiting', true);
    this.emitChange();
  }
  handleUpdateSuccess(data) {
    if (data.firstName === '') {
      data.firstName = this.userProfile.profile.firstName;
    }
    if (data.lastName === '') {
      data.lastName = this.userProfile.profile.lastName;
    }
    if (data.dob === '') {
      data.dob = this.userProfile.profile.dob;
    }
    if (data.department === '') {
      data.department = this.userProfile.profile.department;
    }
    if (data.position === '') {
      data.position = this.userProfile.profile.position;
    }
    this.userProfile.profile = data;
  }
  handleLoginSuccess() {
    this.user = this.user.merge({ isWaiting: false, authenticated: true });
    this.emitChange();
  }

  handleLogoutAttempt() {
    this.user = this.user.set('isWaiting', true);
    this.emitChange();
  }

  handleLogoutSuccess() {
    this.user = this.user.merge({ isWaiting: false, authenticated: false });
    this.emitChange();
  }

}

// Export our newly created Store
export default alt.createStore(UserStore, 'UserStore');
```

Comment: what's the question ?

Comment: Woops , implementing a button that rerenders on click, just the button

Comment: onclick get your value and update state ?

Comment: Yea I would like to obtain a value that indicates whether a employee belongs to another employee or not, if so update the state accordingly.